# Why is gawk adding extra white space between "printf" calls?

Tags: awk, whitespace, bioinformatics, removing-whitespace

I'm working on a script that extracts lines from a GTF File using gawk, and it is adding an extra white space in between successive calls to "printf".  For those unfamiliar with GTF files, they are a common genomic format consisting of 9 tab separated fields where the 9th field stores a list of key - value attribute pairs separated by a combined semicolon and whitespace "; ". The objective is to extract and rows with a specific "gene_name" passed as a single column of text in Input file 1.

Everything in the processing script works as expected EXCEPT that somehow an extra white space is introduced between the final printf iteration in the inner for loop, and the printf statement that inserts a "newline" character.

Example Input File 1:

```
(base) [user@host MouseEnsembl100]$ head gene_names.txt
Cryaa
Cryab
Crygc
```

Example Input GTF File (File 2):

```
(base) [user@host MouseEnsembl100]$ head example.gtf
17  ensembl_havana  gene    31677807    31681733    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; gene_name "Cryaa";
17  havana  transcript  31677807    31681733    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa";
17  havana  exon    31677807    31678189    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa";
17  havana  CDS 31678001    31678189    .   +   0   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa";
17  havana  start_codon 31678001    31678003    .   +   0   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa";
17  havana  exon    31679559    31679681    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa";
```

Processing Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=make_rseqc_bed
#SBATCH --mem=32000
#SBATCH --ntasks=4

TARGETS=/work/abf/MouseEnsembl100/gene_names.txt
TGTLABL=gene_name
GTFPATH=/work/abf/MouseEnsembl100/example.gtf

if [ ! -z $TGTLABL ] && [ ! -z $TARGETS ]
then
    gawk -v lbl=${TGTLABL}\
     -v FS="\t| |;"\
     -v OFS=''\
     -v ORS=''\
     '(NR == FNR) {tgt[$1]; next}
      (NR != FNR) {gsub("; ",";")}
          (NR != FNR)\
              {
                 for(i=0; i<=NF; i++){                     
                     if($i == lbl){
                         gsub("\042","",$(i+1))
                         if($(i+1) in tgt){
                             $(i+1)="\042"$(i+1)"\042"
                             for(j=1; j<=NF;j++){
                                if(j < 9) {
                                    printf($j"\t")
                                }
                                else if( (j % 2) == 1){
                                    printf($j" ")
                                }
                                else if( (j % 2) == 0 && (j+1) < NF){
                                    printf($j"; ")
                                }
                                else if((j+1) == NF){
                                    printf($j";LAST_FIELD")
                                }
                             }
                             printf("%s\n","NEXT LINE")
                         }
                  }   
                 } 
              }' $TARGETS $GTFPATH >> extracted_targets.gtf
fi
```

Example Output:

```
17  ensembl_havana  gene    31677807    31681733    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; gene_name "Cryaa"; NEXT LINE
17  havana  transcript  31677807    31681733    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa"; NEXT LINE
17  havana  exon    31677807    31678189    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa"; NEXT LINE
17  havana  CDS 31678001    31678189    .   +   0   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa"; NEXT LINE
17  havana  start_codon 31678001    31678003    .   +   0   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa"; NEXT LINE
17  havana  exon    31679559    31679681    .   +   .   gene_id "ENSMUSG00000024041"; gene_version "10"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000228716"; gene_name "Cryaa"; NEXT LINE
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying different things I finally realized that by using the field delimiter set `FS="\t| |;"`  Gawk was generating an empty field for the terminal `;` (In my GTF file, every line ends in a semicolon).

When I changed:

```
for(j=1; j<=NF;j++){
```

To:

```
  for(j=1; j<NF;j++){
```

The issue was resolved. Hopefully someone finds this post useful.

Comment: Since you're using gawk, which supports multi-char RS, you could've just set `-v RS=';\n'` instead. Don't do `printf($j"\t")` btw as that'll fail when your input contains any printf formatting characters, do `printf "%s\t", $j` instead.